# How to make Cookie Popup anchor to bottom of screen on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cookies

I have a cookie popup for an upcoming project, and it works great on desktop:
[Screenshot Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ej9s4.jpg). But when I tested it on mobile, it looked like [this trash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xsjpn.png). Does anyone know how to anchor the element to the bottom of the screen on mobile devices? Thanks. [Website Preview](https://unstable.beta.race-life.net/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the width to 100% when the page opens on mobile screen size.

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
   #cookiePopup {
     width: 100%
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, appreciate it!